# How to use Math.Pow properly to avoid getting "There is no argument given corresponds to the required formal pattern 'y' of Math.Pow(double, double)"

Tags: c#

I am getting this error in my code:  There is no argument given corresponds to the required formal pattern 'y' of Math.Pow(double, double).

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AssignmentTwo.Models
{
    public class FutureValueCalculator
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Principal value.")]
        [Range(50000, 1000000, ErrorMessage =
               "Principle value must be between 50,000 to 10,00,000.")]
        public decimal? PrincipleValue { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a yearly interest rate.")]
        [Range(0.1, 10.0, ErrorMessage =
               "Yearly interest rate must be between 0.1 and 10.0.")]
        public decimal? YearlyInterestRate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Compounding periods per year.")]
        [Range(1, 24, ErrorMessage =
               "Compounding period must be between 1 to 24 according to months")]
        public decimal? CompoundingPeriod { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number of years.")]
        [Range(1, 50, ErrorMessage =
               "Number of years must be between 1 and 50.")]
        public int? Years { get; set; }

        public decimal? CalculateFutureValue()
        {
            int? months = Years * 12;
            decimal? monthlyInterestRate = YearlyInterestRate / 12 / 100;
            
            decimal? futureValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
            {
                futureValue = Decimal.ToDouble(Math.Pow((PrincipleValue * (1 + (YearlyInterestRate / CompoundingPeriod)), CompoundingPeriod * Years)));
            }
            return futureValue;
        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your paranthesis are not aligned.
Notice that Pow method expects 2 double inputs whereas your params were decimal.

Also you are trying to convert nullable decimals to double (you may also get exception when dividing with 0) I would recommend improve your code with those validations first, but if you are just targeting to make that code work, below should work.

Also edit your question as well. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about asking.

```
 public decimal? CalculateFutureValue(int? Years, decimal? YearlyInterestRate, decimal? PrincipleValue,
                                         decimal? CompoundingPeriod)
    {
        int? months = Years * 12;
        decimal? monthlyInterestRate = YearlyInterestRate / 12 / 100;
    
        decimal? futureValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < months; i++) {
            futureValue =
                Convert.ToDecimal(
                Math.Pow(
                    Decimal.ToDouble(PrincipleValue.Value * (1 + (YearlyInterestRate.Value / CompoundingPeriod.Value))),
                    Decimal.ToDouble(CompoundingPeriod.Value * Years.Value)
                    )
            );
        }
    
        return futureValue;
    }
```

That is a pretty fragile code.. Again, I would recommend make those input params either not nullable, or at least have some sort of null check before putting them into calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this  `Math.Pow((PrincipleValue * (1 + (YearlyInterestRate / CompoundingPeriod)), CompoundingPeriod * Years))` line, it should be like this.

```
Math.Pow((PrincipleValue * (1 + (YearlyInterestRate / CompoundingPeriod)), CompoundingPeriod * Years), <somthingShouldBePasswedHere>)
```

Because of [Math.Pow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=net-7.0) requires two parameters and you are passing a single parameter in your case.